# error in decoding json file in python project : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, github, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run this github project on my raspberry Pi https://github.com/tdopierre/shga
But I have some errors when I'm starting it. I checked my config.json and it is ok.

```
{
  "telegram_token": "token",
  "telegram_chat_id": "id",
  "vinted": {
      "urls": [
          "https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?order=newest_first"
      ]
  } ,
  "lbc": {
      "urls": [
          "https://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/ile_de_france/"
      ],
      "login": "login",
      "password": "password",
      "use_saved_searches": true
  }
}
```

And this is what I get when starting main.py:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/shga $ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/shga/app.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/shga/app.py", line 42, in main
    process_lbc()
  File "/home/pi/shga/app.py", line 29, in process_lbc
    lbc_handler = LBCHandler(lbc_config)
  File "/home/pi/shga/util/lbc.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._login()
  File "/home/pi/shga/util/lbc.py", line 57, in _login
    bearer = json.loads(response.text)["access_token"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It looks like something is wrong in my config.json, am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository and make sure you are inside the folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/tdopierre/shga.git && cd shga
```

Those commands with a dot are simply hidden folders. Try these:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

This should create a folder named 'env', using python 3 as default.
After creating the virtual environment you should activate it like this:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

(you should see a parenthesis at the beginning of the line containing the name of the environment)

It's time to install the requirements for the project:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I see that a configuration file is required aswell, make sure that is formatted well and should be good to go. **Make sure the environment is activated when you run the application.**

Comment: Thanks, I managed to set it up correctly. I'm still getting errors after editing the file "config.json"
edit : could it come from this line : `.venv/bin/python app.py` that I'm running with `python app.py` ?

Comment: I dont thik to as its really the command. I think you have the config file, upodate your post with the errors so maybe we can understand where it's coming from. Also make sure to run the app while your virtual environment is active.